# Is this と (particle) + したら　or is it "としたら"

Tags: grammar, words

It's an exercise from my textbook where I have to fill in a word from a list. 
The list is: 
なる,
渡る,
話す,
できる,
たいへんな,
降りる.

The sentence in question is as follows:

> 電車を _______ **としたら**、ドアが閉まってしまった。

I don't think that と+したら could make any sense here, but my textbook hasn't taught me the word としたら http://jisho.org/search/toshitara yet so I can't rule it out. That's why I'm asking you what you think.

I would insert 降りる here and translate the sentence as follows:
"If it happens that I exit the train, unfortunately the door will close."

Comment: Is the space to fill after 電車を? Anyway you are correct it is 降りる, in the sense of "when I was about to get off the train the doors shut". However, I knew that expressing "when about to do something..something happened" would use the volitional form (so in your case would be 降りようとしたら).. this makes me doubt a little bit that's why I don't post this as an answer for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

降りる is obviously the verb you want, but I think the exercise must expect you to put it into the tentative form, 降りよう.  降りようとしたら, "When I made to get off", "Just as I was going to get off", would make sense here. I expect you know the rule:

> Tentative form +  とする = make as if to do, be about to do, be going to do, be on the point of doing, try [unsuccessfully] to do.

For example:

> - お風呂に入ろうとすると, "just as I was about to get into the bath [the telephone rang]"
> - 10時になろうとしています "[Radio announcer] It's just coming up to ten o'clock"
> - 窓を開けようとしたが "I tried to open the window [but it was jammed]".

So your completed sentence would mean "Just as I was going to get off the train, the door closed" (or maybe "the damned door" to convey the irritation expressed by しまった)

Answer (score 1):

> 電車を「降りよう」としたら、ドアが閉まってしまった。

When I was getting off the train, unfortunately the door closed.
Literally, when I tried to get off the train, unforfunately the door closed.

降りる must be properly conjugated to 降りよう.